# regx to find word more than 4 words in python 3.x

Tags: regex, python-3.x

In a string, I want to find all words whose length is greater than 4 using the `re` module.

Sample Input:`This is good Python forum and its helping a lot to beginners.`

Output:      `['Python','helping','beginners]`

I tried below but it's not working:

```
match=re.findall(r'([\w]{4}).*',str1)
```

Comment: Please edit to include any steps you have tried so far, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2):

> to find all words whose length greater than **4**

Use the following approach:

```
import re

s = 'This is good Python forum and its helping a lot to beginners.'
result = re.findall(r'\w{5,}', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['Python', 'forum', 'helping', 'beginners']
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It was so simple i was looking for lookahead and assertions.So dumb i am :(